# Where can I find older versions of Angular 2 documentation?

Tags: angular

Angular 2 RC 5 was released a couple of days ago, however I would like to browse docs for RC 4 version. Is this possible?

Comment: in the "menu" of main page-->docs you can choose at bottom the version of the docs (but only has a "completed" versions: v2, v4, v5, v6, v7,v8 ,v9,stable and next)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular team probably uses `typescript-documentation`, which means what you see on `angular.io` docs, is written and comitted to github with `actual code` in the same `typescript` file.

`angular.io` docs have a github link to that file in `bottom-right`.
And as we all know how github works you can just browse through history of a particular document,  <strike>however there is no clear seperation by version, just commit by commit seperation</strike> .

**Update:** You can also choose the `tag (version)` from **top-left** on **github file** shown in second picture. - @Scrambo (comment)

---

Here is the flow with screenshots,

### `One:` [angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)

[image]

### `Two:` [github file latest version](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.5/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts#L12-L189)

[image]

### `Three:` [github file history](https://github.com/angular/angular/commits/2.0.0-rc.5/modules/%40angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts)

[image]

Comment: To add to this, in your second picture at the top left, you can see a drop down box with the text `Tag: 2.0.0-rc5`. You should be able to filter based on what release version you want to look at in that dropdown.